# Change on jQuery select element not reflected on innerHTML/outerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically, I have to create a select element, select an option and then get the string representation of it, selected option included, like so:

```
<option value="2" selected>two</option>
```

I've tried calling several functions which are commented out below, and while all of them do change `selectedOptions` and `value` fields, that change is not visible in `innerHTML` or `outerHTML` of the element.

```js
var select = '<select><option value="1">one</option><option value="2">two</option><option value="3">three</option></select>';

function render() {
  var sel = $(select);
  //sel.attr('value', '2');
  //sel.prop('value', '2');
  //sel.val('2');
   
  return sel[0].outerHTML;
}
  
console.log(render());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What is your overall required objective? are you just trying to dynamically change the contents of a select list? or do you actually need to get an updated string of HTML representing the current state of the select list?

Comment: Why? Sounds like A/B problem

Comment: @scunliffe I'm using DataTables plugin and returning select in their render function for one column where users can only pick from a given set of options. I have to pick their previously chosen value on load. This render function has to return string representation of the element. Easily done with `return select.replace('"2"', '"2" selected');` for instance, but I'd like a cleaner solution.

Comment: @lovrodoe, Do you want like this?? https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/mdJqVab

Comment: @Maniraj Cheers for help, but I'm not the one appending to body, the library does it for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the `selected` attribute to the appropriate item instead:

```js
var select = '<select><option value="1">one</option><option value="2">two</option><option value="3">three</option></select>';

function render() {
  var sel = $(select);
  sel.find("option[value=2]").attr('selected', 'selected');
  return sel[0].outerHTML;
}

console.log(render());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Do you have an explanation for why this change is reflected on the select's outerHTML whereas my use of `attr` function isn't?

Comment: @lovrodoe -- you're trying to set `value` on `select`. I don't think that's a valid attribute on `select`. While I'm not sure whether jQuery has a validation of appropriate attribute names, I tried to add a `selected` attribute on the `option` element, which is in fact a valid attribute of `option`.

Comment: You're right, thanks. I was under impression that these correspond to object's members because doing `sel[0].value = 2` works as does `sel.val(2)` (in general where you'd append them as an object to DOM)